# MongoDB $in operator array max length

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In Meteor I use MongoDB to store a collection of Objects. There is around 500k docs inserted.

I use `Objets.find({ "_id": { "$in": objIds } });` Where objIds is an array of _id. This works fine when I have an array length of 1000 but when I try with 13145 _ids the app stops responding.

Obviously there's already an index on the _id field and also this search probably won't ever happen but I'm not sure if this is normal behavior. Is there a max length for the $in operator? Couldn't find one in the documentation.

Here's my publish in Meteor :

```
Meteor.publish('objetsByIds', function objetsByIdsPublication(objIds) {
      return Objets.find({ "_id": { "$in": objIds } });
  })
```

Comment: There is a 16 megabyte limit on the size of any document, including query documents in MongoDB. 13,145 ObjectIds should not exceed that limit, since each is 12 bytes. How are you iterating over the results? You could be running into memory limits if you are reading all 13,145 into memory.

Comment: I just return the result as this is used in a Meteor subscription. I am probably running out of memory but I am surprised that I do not get an exception from Meteor in the console.

Comment: Are you trying to do a join? On the client (minimongo) or on the server? Can you show your method/publication?

Comment: On the client I am just receiving the cursor and not doing any joins. I added my code in the question. On the client I fetch() the results but there is probably too much. But I put a console.log("blabla") before fetching and it doesn't print at all so apparently it doesn't even reach the client.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know much about Meteor, BUT, MongoDB uses cursors when retrieving large amounts of data, and depending on the driver implementation is how Meteor handle this.

Though you could take a look at cursors [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html), other idea that comes to my mind is to divide the query. So if you know 1000 works well, make a loop where, using mod, you make the results be 1000 documents long.

Comment: Meteor uses cursors as well. I think pagination might be the way to go still.